# 403 while opening a drive link (pdf) with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to open a print window for a shipping label (in pdf form) from a google drive file link.

This is the .gs code I've written so far:

*the drive link is being declared based on an order its associated with, that portion isn't applicable in this instance*

```js
function printPdf() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[4];
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // order ID associated with the label
  const orderQuery = sheet.getRange('S:S').createTextFinder(
    ui.prompt('Enter an order ID', '', ui.ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText()
  ).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();

  let url;
  // drive link is in column 'O'
  if (orderQuery) url = sheet.getRange(orderQuery.getRow(), 15).getValue();
  const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('check-out-modeless');
  template.url = url;
  const html = template.evaluate();
  ui.showModelessDialog(html, 'Print Label');
}
```

and the HTML looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="<?= url ?>" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>
    <script>
      window.print();
      google.script.host.close();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So far I

- made sure the drive like is *id-based* rather than *preview-based*
- verified that the drive link is accessible from my account

  - I used an incognito window as well to avoid conflicts from being logged in to more than one account
- recorded network headers to see if there was any indication of why the server is declining access

Beyond those I can't think of any other way to solve this aside from maybe utilizing blobs & DriveApp

Comment: The URL has this structure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/view

Comment: Every drive link is associated with a pdf of a shipping label. The link I'm using is an *id-based* link, hence the URL structure. The code I've written is being executed perfectly fine, there isn't a direct problem with the code; the problem is that the pdf contents are not being shown because the server is declining the request. I'm trying to figure out how to display the pdf contents so I open a print window for every pdf I search for. Additionally, can you expand on the `/export?` link? What export type? I.e. `/export={what goes here}`

Comment: I think the server is declining the request because you are trying to put a Google Sheets view page inside dialog box which is an iframe inside an iframe inside the Sheets UI. Try an export link like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ssId}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheetId}`. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is an incredibly reproducible problem: 1. create a pdf in your drive and get the shareable link → 2. paste the link into any cell in your sheet → 3. write a script that gets the link as `template.url` and try to open the pdf with `window.print()`. This is clearly an instance of you talking about problem `X` while I'm talking about problem `Y`. Let me know if you think there is something I should add to my question so it is easier to work with.

Comment: If your question is "how do I convert a share link to an export link", please state that explicitly in the question. Chances are that the "shareable link" you mention does not point to a PDF file but to an HTML page that encapsulates a PDF viewer. The question includes code to locate a cell and retrieve a link from that cell, all of which is irrelevant to the question. To improve the question, replace the code with an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The MRE should include an export link to a publicly shared sample PDF file, or a share link to be converted.